# Simple noob App crashes every time.. (null)?

Tags: java, android

I think that

```
Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.tutorial1);
    bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

is equal to "Null".

( I read it somewhere but did not see a fix to it)

If that isn't the problem plz I don't know..

Thx for any help I can get.

Sincerely, Robin

**activity_main Code:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotoKanal2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gotoKanal3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/tv_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotoKanal3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/tv_3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tutorial2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="TUTORIALONE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tutorial2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gotoKanal6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="-||- 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotoKanal6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/tv_6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotoKanal1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gotoKanal2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/tv_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**mainifest Code:** Ignore all the .tv

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Robin.Robin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.Robin.Robin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="myMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.CLEARSCREEN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".tutorialOne"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.TUTORIALONE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".tv2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.tv2"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".tv3"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.tv3"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Robin.Robin.tv4"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.tv4"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".tv5"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.tv5"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".tv6"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.Robin.Robin.tv6"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**splash Code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/default_320x480" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**myMeny.java Code:**

```
 package com.Robin.Robin;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class myMenu extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.tutorial1);
        bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.Robin.Robin.TUTORIALONE"));
            }
        });

            Button bgotoKanal4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoKanal4);
            bgotoKanal4.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv4"));


                    Button bgotoKanal2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoKanal2);
                    bgotoKanal2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv2"));


                            Button bgotoKanal3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoKanal3);
                            bgotoKanal3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv3"));


                                    Button bgotoKanal1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoKanal1);
                                    bgotoKanal1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv1"));


                                            Button bgotoKanal5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoKanal5);
                                            bgotoKanal5.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                     TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv5"));


                                                    Button bgotoKanal6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoKanal6);
                                                    bgotoKanal6.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                            startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv6"));


                                                        }
                                                    } );
                                                }
                                            } );
                                        }
                                    } );
                                }
                            } );
                        }
                    } );
                }
            } );



        }



    }
```

**MainActivity code:**

```
package com.Robin.Robin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mpSplash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.javaintro);
    mpSplash.start();

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while(logoTimer < 5000){
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;
                }
                startActivity(new Intent("com.Robin.Robin.CLEARSCREEN"));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }


    };
    logoTimer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mpSplash.release();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    mpSplash.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mpSplash.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

Comment: 1. post LogCat (check your Eclipse for the logcat view) 2. don't paste your complete project here... otherwise I request to get payed per line of code!

Comment: It's definitely not a good idea to nest `OnClickListeners` like this (unless you like triangles that much), it reduces the readibility of your code and increases chances of errors). Consider using some sort of counter variable (it's not entirely clear what you're doing).

Comment: I'm doing an Intro screen followed by a mainScreen whit 6 buttons and and then sex screens which the button goes to.
Sorry for thread, I'm new and trying to learn. @A--C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.tutorial1);
```

should be

```
Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
```

Because your Button in xml is defined as

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ...
```

Which will be defined in `R.id`, therefore, you retrieve it as `R.id.tutorial1`

 **In addition** to the problem, did you forget to close your OnClickListener?

```
bgotoKanal2.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            startActivity (new Intent ("package com.Robin.Robin.tv2"));
                      });//closes the listener, add it to each one.
```